# custom page template not showing up

Tags: theming

I have created a new page template page--membership.tpl.php and placed it in the /templates folder inside of my theme (the same folder as my regular page.tpl.php file). I flushed the cache, but my page sitename.com/membership is not picking up the changes. (I even tried deleting all of the content of the tpl file to see if it would mess up the page, but nothing.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of `page--membership.tpl.php` not working for `sitename.com/membership` may be:
Drupal used templates as `page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php` based on the internal path of the current page. Do not confuse the internal path to path aliases (Pathauto module uses path aliases) which are not accounted for.

To create the template for `page--membership.tpl.php` one may try one of the following methods:

1. Create template as `page--node--[NODE_ID].tpl.php`, here replace the `[NODE_ID]` with the node id of `membership` page.
2. To get recognize the aliased paths, you have to add the aliased path as part of the theme suggestions: https://groups.drupal.org/node/130944#comment-425189

Comment: yeah, you're right. I used the internal path page--node--[NODE_ID].tpl.php and it worked.